# php Undefined variable when using $_POST['']

Tags: php

.

in my project i have two pages , first page has a form (check-boxes) , and the second page will print the values of the checked boxes when i click submit/print button .

> if( isset($_POST['do']))
>
> {
>
> $mid = $_POST['mid'];
>
> }

once i click the " do button "  in the first page ,  i go to the second page , then take the checked box values by $_POST['mid']

and when i click on the print button it should print the values of the checked box

```
      if(isset($_POST['print']))
      {

       foreach($mid as $values)
       echo $values;

      }
```

but it gives me  :

> Undefined variable: mid .,
>   and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

notice that it works when i put the foreach statement in the first -if-
: if( isset($_POST['do'])) , but i dont want it be like that.

and thank you all

Comment: You should use `isset`. A checkbox does not set a value in $_POST if unchecked. If it is not set, you can set a value yourself if you like.

Comment: thank you daniel .. but im already using isset .

Comment: Just addressing the 'but i dont want it be like that' ... There is no way around it. You NEED to use `isset` to get the status of that variable.

Comment: there is not enough code to support the question. this being your missing HTML form and possibly more PHP.

Comment: `$mid` is assigned to a non existing `$_POST['mid']`. Use `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to a third page you must pass the variable to that page as well. So from your html form you post the variable which is saved with the `name` of the input type. We will assign the name of the input types value to a variable  on the second page and then echo it to the screen.

Html Form

```
    <form action="myPhpPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Male">Male</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Female">Female</input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

myPhpPage.php

```
  <?php
    // turn the check boxed gender to a variable called $myGender
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    // now print your variable to the screen
    // there is no reason to move to a new page for this,
    //if you do go to a new page then you need to pass the variable to the // //new page as well.
    echo $gender;
$_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
<input type="button" value="Print" href="printPage.php" />
    ?>
```

printPage.php

```
    $gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
    echo $gender;
```

Add this to the top of all your pages that you want the session

```
session_start();
```

Comment: thanks .. but i need to print the values of checkboxes  when i click the print button ,

Comment: ok print button on the second page?

Comment: I updated so when you click print it takes your to a print page. Also I showed you how to store the variables in a session so you can use them again.

Comment: thanks for your effort with me .. i used the session before  like this  

if(isset($_POST['do']))
{   

   $mid = $_POST['mid'];
   $dis = $_POST['dis'];
   $_SESSION['mid'] =$mid;
    $_SESSION['dis'] =$dis;

}


    if(isset($_POST['print']))
    {

            foreach($_SESSION['mid'] as $values)
              echo $values ;
    }

but the same error
Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: why the code looks iike this way ! 
do you have facebook account  ? :/

Comment: Add this to the top of the page session_start();